Why are round nose cones more aerodynamical than pointy
I am wondering why round nose cones are aerodynamical than pointy nose cones. Lets say that the air is flowing exactly perpendicular to the pointy nose cone, why is the round one still better than the pointy. Lets also assume that the oncoming air is traveling at a subsonic speed. One theory I have is that air is flowing faster around the pointy nose cone and therefore the pressure is lower on the surface and then that causes more drag than the round. I dont know if that is correct or If there is another explanation. Could someone who knows this explain it?

Does this answer your question?

Good find, Wyatt!  Peter's answer suggests that a pointy nose is draggier when flow isn't axial, and says that a rounded nose suffers less from this.  Is that enough of an answer to "more aerodynamical" (less drag)?

@CamilleGoudeseune Thanks! I’m not sure if a round nose is more aerodynamic. The linked answer doesn’t mention that, and it wouldn’t really make sense. So, I’d say the only way a rounded nose would be more aerodynamic is when flow isn’t axial. In that case yes, I’d say that’s the best way to answer this.
